# Converting csv RDD to map

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a large CSV( > 500 MB), which I take into a spark RDD, and I want to store it to a large Map[String, Array[Long]].
The CSV has multiple columns but I require only two for the time being. The first and second column, and is of the form:

```
A 12312 [some_value] ....
B 123123[some_value] ....
A 1222 [some_value] ....
C 1231 [some_value] ....
```

I want my map to basically group by the string and store an array of long
so, for the above case, my map would be:
{"A": [12312, 1222], "B": 123123, "C":1231}

But since this map would be huge, I can't simply do this directly. tsca

I take the CSV in a sql.dataframe

My code so far(Looks incorrect though):

```
def getMap(df: sql.DataFrame, sc: SparkContext): RDD[Map[String, Array[Long]]] = {
    var records = sc.emptyRDD[Map[String, Array[Long]]]
    val rows: RDD[Row] =  df.rdd
    rows.foreachPartition( iter => {
      iter.foreach(x =>
        if(records.contains(x.get(0).toString)){
        val arr = temp_map.getOrElse()
          records = records + (x.get(0).toString -> (temp_map.getOrElse(x.get(0).toString) :+ x.get(1).toString.toLong))
      }
        else{
          val arr = new Array[Long](1)
          arr(0) = x.get(1).toString.toLong
          records = records + (x.get(0).toString -> arr)
        }



      )
    })

  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to find the llist of column 2 for each key column 1?

Comment: I am basically trying to group by column 1 and store the result in a map where if I give a string as key, it gives me an array of values(column 2 values) corresponding to the key in the CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then

You could `groupBy` first column and `collect_list` for the second `column`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val newDF = df.groupBy("column1").agg(collect_list("column2"))
newDF.show(faslse)

val rdd = newDF.rdd.map(r => (r.getString(0), r.getAs[List[Long]](1)))
```

This will give you `RDD[(String, List[Long])]` where the string will be unique

Comment: I was about to post the same answer. GroupBy should do the job.

Comment: I wrote code for the problem so thought to post it :P :D

Comment: Thanks, how do I query the RDD[(String, List[Long])] for a given key x?

Comment: What query do you want to make ? you can use `filter`

Comment: I basically want a fast retrieval of the list against a particular string key. That's why I was looking for a map

Comment: I guess the performance will be same with both case. You can also look in to https://github.com/amplab/spark-indexedrdd